# Broken Directory Icon Overlay Image

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, icons, overlay

How would I go about tracking down the cause of (what looks like) a broken directory icon overlay? Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about

[image: Example of broken overlay image.]

I've had a look at the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers` key in the registry but nothing jumps out at me as the cause. I've also tried checking for a problem `desktop.ini` as well as rebuilding the icon cache.